# Naming Conventions?

Tags: kotlin

I am following this official code style guide for Kotlin (link goes to the section in particular): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#property-names

This is my first time following a Code Style guide, so I want to verify, are they saying that all variable names *that aren't immutable* should be in **UpperCamelCase**?

The second example shows a mutable list, so I assumed that it is only for variables that hold array like data.

So my conclusion was that I should use the third example's UpperCamelCase for all regular variable names, like a `findViewById<Button>` *val*.

What I assumed seems wrong, so is it the LowerCamelCase for such variables given in the second example? And only special objects get UpperCamelCase? I am asking for simple things like `findViewById<Button>`,  **Strings**, **Ints**, **Booleans**, etc.

Comment: You need to quote what you are linking to. Links go bad over time. [ask]

Comment: @Rob I was in a hurry and I was editing them in at first, apologies. When I get the time I will edit this, I've got an assignment to rush through haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you made a confusion reading the documentation.
But to clarify:

- Deeply immutable data (like constants): `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`
- References to singleton objects: `UpperCamelCase`
- All other cases: `lowerCamelCase`

So for your cases of findViewById, Strings, Ints, Booleans (since your Strings and Ints aren't constants), then you should use `lowerCamelCase`.

Comment: Thank you! That's all I need, yes I was confused.

Comment: For the record, sometimes the term `camelCase` is used only when starting with lowere-case, and `PascalCase` when starting with a capital. There's also `kebab-case` and `snake_case`…

Comment: @gidds That is very useful to know, thanks for commenting that.